# c# excel addin error

Tags: c#, excel, exception

I try to create my first Excel add in.
I'm working on Visual Studio 2013 and Excel 2013 too.

The problem, when I try to debug my addIn, Excel launches but it fires the following exception

```
Value does not fall within the expected range in System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32 Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)
```

I didn't modified the code yet and it's exactly what is generated by default.

I don't know what it could come from. Does someone have a solution please ?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [ClickOnce error: Value does not fall within the expected range](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1166233/464709).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's not about ClickOnce. And all the solutions given in that post didn't work for me.